# Issue in spanning threads parallelly in loop c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

i have below code to call method ThreadProc in multiple threads.  ResultCallback is the call back method.
ThreadProc calls a stored procedure and returns records and forms dataset.  the dataset is passed back to ResultCallback, where i want to process these records further.

```
 int count = 30000;
 int start = 1;
 int batch = 10000;
 var tasks = new List<Task>();
while (start <= count)
        {
            var s = start;
            var b = start + (batch - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Processing records from {0} to {1}", s, b );
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                new MyClass().ThreadProc(s, b,new ExampleCallback(ResultCallback));
            }));
            start += batch;
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Callback method is

```
 public static void ResultCallback(DataSet ds, int start)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Finished processing batch starting with {0}. " +
            "Processed batch started with org id {1} lines.", start, ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
    }
```

the issue here is that, in SSMS to return 40000 records a stored procedure takes 7 minutes.  in my multi thread program, i spanned 4 threads each to return 10000 records.  it still takes 7 minutes indicating that the 4 threads is behaving like one single thread.

my expectation is that since am slicing the record size to 10000 per thread, the total time to get 40000 records should be 7 min/4. approxmi 2 min.
why this is not happening?

below is the code of ThreadProc method

```
 public void ThreadProc(int start, int batch, ExampleCallback callbackDelegate)
    {
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_D", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //the 2 codes after this comment is where you assign value to the parameters you
            //have on your stored procedure from SQL
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Int).Value = start;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch", SqlDbType.Int).Value = batch;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 18000;
            da.Fill(dataset); //this is where you put values you get from the Select command to a 
                              //dataset named ds, reason for this is for you to fetch the value from DB to code behind

        }
        if (callback != null)
            callback(dataset, start);

        Console.WriteLine(this.start);
    }
```

How to make the threads run in parallel and get all output in 10 sec instead of 30 sec.

Thanks in advance.

=================================
Update:

i compare the results, i tried to call the same method synchronously and asynchronously(via tasks).  below is the code

sync code

```
 while (start <= count)
        {

            MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1(start, batch, new ExampleCallback1(ResultCallback));
            obj.ThreadProc();

            start += batch;
        }
```

async

```
while (start <= count)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var s = start;
            var b = batch;
            //Account Number
            tasks = new[]
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    MyClass sdse = new MyClass1();
                    var data = new MyClass2( connectionString);
                    data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                    data.ThreadProc(s, b, new ExampleCallback(sdse.EncryptMethod));
                    ////Console.WriteLine("Processed records from {0} to {1} on thread #{2}.",
                    //                  s, s + (b - 1), data.ThreadNum);
                })
   }
}
```

i see that the sync call is getting the results in less time where as async call is taking more time.

not sure what wrong am doing here.

Comment: Is it possible that the `proc_D` stored procedure locks a table in the database during its whole execution? In that case your bottleneck would be the database, and there would be nothing you could do in your C# code to speed things up.

Comment: Changed by question a bit. thanks.

Comment: Could you show the SQL code of the `proc_D` stored procedure?

Comment: ;WITH tmp AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY pk ) AS N, pk, 
    a FROM      mytbl
   )
   SELECT pk,a
     FROM tmp WHERE n BETWEEN @Start AND (@Start + (@Batch-1))

Comment: Try using one static SQL DB connection instead of using new connection for every thread (ThreadProc should contain only parameters "@Start" and "@Batch" initialization plus execution/calling for Stored Procedure).

Comment: Is your database located in a remote machine? The bottleneck could be the data traffic through the network. Also does your local machines have multiple cores? If your are running in a single-core machine, then the bottleneck could be the `da.Fill(dataset)` command.

Comment: @ATTA how do I do this? Declare a static connection variable and open it in constructor? And use it in thread proc?

Comment: @user1447718 1) declare SqlConnection con at class level 2) Make another constructor to initialize connection 3) Add parameters in ThreadProc(int start,int batch,con); instead of passing 'start' and 'batch' value in constructor, pass these values in method ThreadProc 4) Remove Using() from ThreadProc